# In .NET, at runtime: How to get the default value of a type from a Type object?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default value of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490244/default-value-of-a-type)

In C#, to get the default value of a Type, i can write...

```
var DefaultValue = default(bool);`
```

But, how to get the same default value for a supplied Type variable?.

```
public object GetDefaultValue(Type ObjectType)
{
    return Type.GetDefaultValue();  // This is what I need
}
```

Or, in other words, what is the implementation of the "default" keyword?

Comment: This is pretty much duplicate of ["Default value of a type"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490244/default-value-of-a-type). Codeka gives a good [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490244/default-value-of-a-type/2490274#2490274) which I think will help you.

Comment: return default(ObjectType) doesn't work?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think that Frederik's function should in fact look like this:

```
public object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
{
    if (t.IsValueType)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is!
I tested it with struct, enum, value and reference types and works pretty fine.
thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You should probably exclude the `Nullable<T>` case too, to reduce a few CPU cycles:

```
public object GetDefaultValue(Type t) {
    if (t.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) == null) {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are optimizing for Nullables at the cost of non-Nullable types.