# Default value and linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Why this simple code doesnt work?

```
var abc = new[]{1,2,3,4}.Select(x => default(typeof(x)));
```

i expect something like array of zeros but get compiler error. So how i can default values in lambda expressions?

In my real application i have meta class with type Type

```
public class FieldInfo
{
     public Type type
}
```

I get `IEnumerable<FieldInfo>` as parameter to my method and want return an array of default values for each type (`object[]`)

Comment: what (the hell) are you trying to do? :). in other words, what value do you expect in `abc`?

Comment: What error do you get? if you know its an int, why do you use `typeof`?

Comment: If you just want an int array of size 4 all set to zero then just create the int array.  It will initialise each element to zero anyway.

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: @bas i have a more complex code it just a simplified example

Comment: @Neir0 that I believe :). But the problem is that we have no clue about what you are trying to achieve. Can you try to make that clear? E.g. by specifying your expected result

Comment: Hm, the `default` for class types is always null, I'm not sure what you're expecting as output if it's all returned in an object[]. Objects created using the default constructor?

Comment: @Neir0 doesn't Jon Skeets answer solve your problem then? He provides an extension method `SelectDefaults` with generics. Maybe you can get rid of your `Type` field all together. It remains a bit abstract to me. Maybe others can have less difficulties to follow.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson but not null for structs.

Comment: @Neir0 oops i made a blunder..

Comment: @bas No, because John's solution return default value for collection type not for each element of my collection.

Comment: @Neir0: No, it returns the default value for the *element* type of the collection type. Now you've actually said what you're trying to achieve, it will be easier to implement. (I've edited my answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
var abc = new[]
{
    1, 2, 3, 4
}
.Select(x = > {
    var xType = x.GetType();
    if (xType.IsValueType)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(xType);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
})
```

Comment: Yeah! That is what im looking! Did not excpect that it is so hard to do.

Comment: Note that this will also create an instance of `Nullable<int>` etc, which will then be boxed to null.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I've checked that `Activator.CreateInstance(new int?(1).GetType())` actually returns 0 (apparently, because `new int?(1).GetType()` is `Int32`). So, one would never get a boxed to null instance this way which is different from an `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Nullable<int>))`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @aush: You're right - if we're calling `GetType()` as per your answer, it wouldn't be a problem. However, with the OP's actual scenario where the type is from a separate property, it could be.

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem:

```
typeof(x)
```

You're using the `typeof` operator as if it's a method call, taking a value. It's not. It needs a *compile-time* type name or type parameter (or unbound type such as `Dictionary<,>`, or `void`).

The same is try with the `default` operator.

So that's what's *wrong* - but without knowing what you're trying to achieve, we can't actually advise you on how to fix it. You might just want something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.Select(x => default(T));
}
```

Then this:

```
var abc = new[]{1,2,3,4}.SelectDefault().ToArray();
```

... would give you an `int[]` with all values zero.

EDIT: Now we have more information, it's easier to provide what you want, which is basically a method to get the default value from a `Type`, boxing as appropriate:

```
public static object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
{
    // Non-nullable value types should be boxed, basically
    if (type.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) == null)
    {
        // Not the swiftest approach in the world, but it works...
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }

    // Everything else defaults to null
    return null;
}
```

So you'd have something like:

```
var defaults = fields.Select(field => GetDefaultValue(field.type));
```

(Where `field` is a `FieldInfo` as per the question - I'm deliberately *not* calling `GetType()` here.)

Comment: You could use `x.GetType()` to resolve the immediate issue, but depending what the OP wants it may not be the best solution

Comment: @just.another.programmer: The `default` part would still fail then... without knowing the point here, it's very hard to give more specific help :(

Comment: There's a typo in your use of `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`. That method's return type is `System.Type`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Sorry, yes - it was meant to be comparing that with null. Edited now.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the default value at runtime this way, `default()` and `typeof()` are compile time features. But you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686678/in-net-at-runtime-how-to-get-the-default-value-of-a-type-from-a-type-object) suggestion. It uses `Activator.CreateInstance` to get the default value for a value type at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs a compile-time type:

```
var abc = new[]{1,2,3,4}.Select(x => default(Int32));
```

will generate all 0's. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with this, though, because all this does is return an empty array with the default value.