# C#: How to find the default value for a run-time Type?

Tags: c#, strong-typing

So given a static type in your code you can do

```
var defaultMyTypeVal = default(MyType);
```

How would you do the same thing given a variable of Type so you can use it during runtime?

In other words how do I implement the following method without a bunch of if statements or using Generics (because I will not know the type I'm passing into the method at compile time)?

```
public object GetDefaultValueForType(Type type) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: I have already answered this issue in the following post: [Determine default value of an arbitrary Type at run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490244/default-value-of-a-type/7881481#7881481) Hope this helps ... Mark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490244/default-value-of-a-type) post:

```
public object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
{
    if (t.IsValueType) {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    } else {
        return null;
}
```