# Is there a way to search a List<T> using a partially populated object?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Would like to be able to populate any properties of an object and search a collection for objects that match the given properties.

```
class Program
{
    static List<Marble> marbles = new List<Marble> { 
        new Marble {Color = "Red", Size = 3},
        new Marble {Color = "Green", Size = 4},
        new Marble {Color = "Black", Size = 6}
    };

    static void Main()
    {
        var search1 = new Marble { Color = "Green" };
        var search2 = new Marble { Size = 6 };
        var results = SearchMarbles(search1);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Marble> SearchMarbles(Marble search)
    {
        var results = from marble in marbles
                      //where ???
                      //Search for marbles with whatever property matches the populated properties of the parameter
                      //In this example it would return just the 'Green' marble
                      select marble;
        return results;
    }

    public class Marble
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to propose the generic solution which will work with any number of properties and with any object. It will also be usable in Linq-To-Sql context - it will translate well to sql.

First, start by defining function which will test if the given value is to be treated as a non-set, e.g:

```
static public bool IsDefault(object o)
{
    return o == null || o.GetType().IsValueType && Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType()).Equals(o);
}
```

Then, we will have a function which constructs a Lambda expression with test against the values of all set properties in `search` object:

```
static public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetComparison<T>(T search)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");

    var props = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                where p.CanRead && !IsDefault(p.GetValue(search, null))
                select Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(param, p.Name),
                    Expression.Constant(p.GetValue(search, null))
                );

    var expr = props.Aggregate((a, b) => Expression.AndAlso(a, b));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, param);         
    return lambda;
}
```

We can use it on any `IQueryable`:

```
public static IEnumerable<Marble> SearchMarbles (Marble search)
{
    var results = marbles.AsQueryable().Where(GetComparison(search));
    return results.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: @fyrplace great to hear that. :) I would appreciate if you up-vote my answer too. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Admittedly, it is interesting and take me time. First, you need to get all properties of `search` object which have value different with default value, this method is generic using reflection:

```
var properties = typeof (Marble).GetProperties().Where(p =>
                {
                    var pType = p.PropertyType;
                    var defaultValue = pType.IsValueType 
                            ? Activator.CreateInstance(pType) : null;

                    var recentValue = p.GetValue(search);

                    return !recentValue.Equals(defaultValue);
                });
```

Then you can use LINQ `All` to filter:

```
var results = marbles.Where(m => 
                         properties.All(p => 
                         typeof (Marble).GetProperty(p.Name)
                                        .GetValue(m) == p.GetValue(search)));
```

P.s: This code has been tested

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate Filter class like this:

```
class Filter
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public bool Matches(Marble m)
    {
        var T = typeof(Marble);
        var prop = T.GetProperty(PropertyName);
        var value = prop.GetValue(m);
        return value.Equals(PropertyValue);
    }
}
```

You can use this Filter as follows:

```
var filters = new List<Filter>();
filters.Add(new Filter() { PropertyName = "Color", PropertyValue = "Green" });

//this is essentially the content of SearchMarbles()
var result = marbles.Where(m => filters.All(f => f.Matches(m)));

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Color + ", " + r.Size);
}
```

You could use DependencyProperties to get rid of typing the property name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a property is unpopulated if it has the default value (i.e. `Color == null` and `Size == 0`):

```
var results = from marble in marbles
              where (marble.Color == search.Color || search.Color == null)
                 && (marble.Size == search.Size || search.Size == 0)
              select marble;
```

Comment: OP could do int? Size. Nullable to be explicit.

Comment: This will work if `Marble` has only 2 properties - `Color` and `Size`.

Comment: @Science_Fiction Assuming `Size` is some physical measurement, `0` as a non-populated property makes sense.

Comment: @Krizz That's the definition of `Marble` given by the OP. But the `where` clause would need to be more complex for each additional property that needs testing.

Comment: My real project has many more properties, was hoping this could be done without explicit property usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could override equals in your Marbles class

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Marble;

        if (null == other) return false;

        return other.Color == this.color && other.size == this.size; // (etc for your other porperties
    }
```

and then you could search by

```
return marbles.Where(m => search == m);
```

Comment: Don't forget to also override the GetHashCode if you wish to use in Dictionary.

Comment: Liking this approach, it still requires property usage but it would make for queries like I was aiming for.

Comment: You could combine this with Desperter's reflection concept so you could implement Equals via reflecting through all the properties and still have your queries be simple equality checks.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection, this method will work on **all types**, regardless of how many or what type of properties they contain.

Will skip any properties that are not filled out (null for ref type, default value for value type). If it finds two properties that are filled out that do not match returns false. If all filled-out properties are equal returns true.

```
IsPartialMatch(object m1, object m2)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = m1.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object v1 = property.GetValue(m1, null);
        object v2 = property.GetValue(m2, null);
        object defaultValue = GetDefault(property.PropertyType);

        if (v1.Equals(defaultValue) continue;
        if (v2.Equals(defaultVAlue) continue;
        if (!v1.Equals(v2)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

To apply it to your example

```
public static IEnumerable<Marble> SearchMarbles(Marble search)
{
    return marbles.Where(m => IsPartialMatch(m, search))
}
```

---

GetDefault() is method from this post, [Programmatic equivalent of default(Type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325426/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaulttype)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid targeting specific properties, you could use reflection. Start by defining a function that returns the default value of a type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490274/111794) for a simple solution, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881481/111794) for something more elaborate).

Then, you can write a method on the `Marble` class, which takes an instance of `Marble` as a filter:

```
public bool MatchesSearch(Marble search) {
    var t = typeof(Marble);
    return !(
        from prp in t.GetProperties()
        //get the value from the search instance
        let searchValue = prp.GetValue(search, null)
        //check if the search value differs from the default
        where searchValue != GetDefaultValue(prp.PropertyType) &&
              //and if it differs from the current instance
              searchValue != prp.GetValue(this, null)
        select prp
    ).Any();
}
```

Then, the `SearchMarbles` becomes:

```
public static IEnumerable<Marble> SearchMarbles(Marble search) {
    return
        from marble in marbles
        where marble.MatchesSearch(search)
        select marble;
}
```

Comment: I believe `||` should be `&&` because you want to check if there are any properties where searchValue isn't the default value *and* isn't equal to the Marble's property's value.