# Get property info of all properties which values currently equal 'default'

Tags: c#, reflection, types, expression, equality

So, I need to retrieve all properties of an instance which currently have a value that matches the default value of their respective type. Something along the lines of

```
GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => 
    x.GetValue(this).Equals(default(x.PropertyType)));
```

This obviously doesn't work because it seems 'x' cannot be resolved anymore at this point. What could I do?

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The immediate problem is that `default` expects a type, not a value, not even a value of type `System.Type`. That's far from the only problem, though.

Comment: @hvd Care to explain what you mean by 'the only problem'?

Comment: One other problem is that if a property of reference type or nullable value type is `null` (the default value of the type), then `x.GetValue(this).Equals(whatever)` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. Another problem is that `x.GetValue(this)` will throw an exception if you have any indexers.

Comment: @hvd Oh dear. Well, a NullReferenceException can easily be avoided, but how to overcome the indexers problem? Binding flags on GetProperties()?

Comment: For that problem, I think you should be able to check `!x.GetIndexParameters().Any()`, but I'm not completely certain.

Comment: @hvd Other answers on SO also suggest GetIndexParameters(). Will definitely test this, but it seems to be the right way. Also upboats for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Basically I would do something like this: `GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => 
    Object.Equals(x.GetValue(this, null), Activator.CreateInstance(x.PropertyType)))`. It has some border cases for indexed properties, but handles the "common cases".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is slightly different. You cannot pass a runtime instance of `Type` to default. Your problem can be simplified to this:

```
var type = typeof (string);
var defaultValue = default(type); // doesn't work
```

That doesn't work. Instead, you want to get the default value at run time, which has been answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490244/default-value-of-a-type-at-runtime).